# How can display a random icons into cards using *ngFor of angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I try to display a random icons into the bootstrap cards  using *ngFor in Angular. I thinking define an array inside the typescript with the diferent 10 icons. And dependens of the number of elements there displaying into HTML cards with random icons..

Hope I can explain well .  Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** after *Eliseo's* suggestion in the comments below:

Add your icons to an array and randomize it:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    iconsArray: string[] = [
        "icon0.svg",
        "icon1.svg",
        "icon2.svg",
        "icon3.svg",
        "icon4.svg",
        "icon5.svg",
        "icon6.svg",
        "icon7.svg",
        "icon8.svg",
        "icon9.svg",
    ];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.shuffleArray();
    }

    shuffleArray() {
        this.iconsArray = this.iconsArray
            .map(x => ({ order: Math.random(), value: x }))
            .sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order)
            .map(x => x.value);
    }
}
```

Then, in your .html, loop through the array using *ngFor and create the bootstrap cards you want:

```
<div *ngFor="let icon of iconsArray" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" [src]="'/icons/' + icon" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, if you're displaying the cards in random places on the screen and can't use `*ngFor`, then you can create a function that delivers a random icon to you every time you call it, like so:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    counter = 0;

    iconsArray: string[] = [
        "icon0.svg",
        "icon1.svg",
        "icon2.svg",
        "icon3.svg",
        "icon4.svg",
        "icon5.svg",
        "icon6.svg",
        "icon7.svg",
        "icon8.svg",
        "icon9.svg",
    ];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.shuffleArray();
    }

    shuffleArray() {
        this.iconsArray = this.iconsArray
            .map(x => ({ order: Math.random(), value: x }))
            .sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order)
            .map(x => x.value);
    }

    getNextRandomIcon() {
        return this.iconsArray[counter++];
    }
}
```

Then, in your .html, any time you want to display a random icon in your bootstrap card, just call `getNextRandomIcon()`. Since it returns the icons from a shuffled array, the card that you'll get will be random:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" [src]="'/icons/' + getNextRandomIcon()" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you has a strange way to shuffle, why not `this.iconsArray=this.iconsArray.map(x=>({order:Math.random(),value:x}).sort((a,b)=>a.order-b.order).map(x=>x.value)`?

Comment: Yes, this is the world of programming... You can have many ways to solve a problem. Your way looks very clever. I'll change my solution. Thanks

Comment: @Eliseo - thanks for the suggestion. I updated the answer with your code improvement.

Comment: Thanks Guys por your faster answer... It works ... but  I need to display one random icon per card... any suggestion for that????

Comment: Just updated the answer. Check to see if this answers your needs.